# Using NextUI Pressable Card and Modals with React useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextui

I am using Next.js and the NextUI component library to create a pressable NextUI card, where upon clicking, will open up a NextUI modal. I have customized the card component in a myCard.js file. I have customized the desired modal component in a myModal.js file. I will be rendering the two in an index.js file where all of my other components get rendered. My current implementation has a pressable card, but when clicking on the card, the modal does not show up.

myCard.js:

```
const myCard = ({openModal}) =>
   *** setup code ***
   <Card 
      className={myCard}
      radius="lg"
      onPress={openModal}
      isPressable
   >
   *** more code ***
```

myModal.js:

```
const myModal = ({isModalOpen, closeModal}) => {
   *** setup code ***
   return (
      <Modal
         isOpen={isModalOpen}
         onClose={closeModal}
      >
         <ModalContent>
             {(onClose) => (
                <>
                  *** modal content ***
             }
         </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
   );
```

index.js

```
*** some other code ***

const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

return (
  <ListCard openModal={openModal}/>
  <DetailCard 
      isOpen={isModalOpen}
      onClose={closeModal}
  />
*** other code ***
)
```

My best guess is that the since my components are in separate files, the state values are not being communicated properly. (If I replace myCard with just a button, it works as expected). What is the most optimal way to get the pressable Card to function properly as a button that opens up the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically,  you want to make a Card which when clicked shows a Modal !

With respect to NextUI documentation you won't even need to use any states for handling Opening & Closing of Modal.

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();
```

Look at the 1st Example : https://nextui.org/docs/components/modal#usage

They have provided a hook, which handles all this states. You just have to set them on your `Card` component. Card has `isPressable` prop, you pass

```
<Card onPress={onOpen} isPressable={true} >
```

- Yes you should **keep the component** that opens Modal **together** with modal or else you have to pass props this makes it unnecessarily difficult.
- Instead keep them together, & handle opening closing using `useDisclosure()` hook.

**Below is a component I made :**

**PressableCard.js**
*Import it in a page & use.*

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Card, CardBody, Modal, ModalBody, ModalContent, ModalFooter, ModalHeader, useDisclosure } from "@nextui-org/react";
const PressableCard = () => {

    const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();

    console.log("isOpen : ", isOpen);

    return (
        <>
            <Card onPress={onOpen} isPressable={true} >
                {/* PASS  onOpen TO onPress EVENT LISTENER*/}
                <CardBody>
                    <p>CLICK THIS CARD !!</p>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} isDismissable={false}>
                {/* PASS isOpen STATE FROM  useDisclosure HOOK*/}
                <ModalContent>

                    {(onClose) => (
                        <>
                            <ModalHeader >MODAL HEADER</ModalHeader>
                            <ModalBody>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, officiis?
                                </p>

                            </ModalBody>
                            <ModalFooter>
                                <Button color="danger" variant="light"
                                    onPress={onClose}>
                                    {/* PASS  onClose FUNCTION TO onPress EVENT LISTENER*/}
                                    CLOSE
                                </Button>
                                <Button color="success" variant="light"
                                    onPress={onClose}>
                                    {/* PASS  onClose OR ANY OTHER FUNCTION TO onPress EVENT LISTENER*/}
                                    ACCEPT
                                </Button>
                            </ModalFooter>
                        </>
                    )}
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

export default PressableCard
```

**Explaination :**

'use client' because these components cannot be rendered server-side as it uses events. Remove 'use client' & read the error.

I have kept Card & Modal together, passed these states/values & functions
`const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();`

**Card :**

Made Card pressable & passed a function on its onPress event:

```
isPressable={true}
onPress={onOpen}
```

**Modal :**

Modal is opened/closed based on

```
isOpen={isOpen}
```

so Modal's isOpen = isOpen from useDisclosure.

Similarly, Modal's  onOpenChange={onOpenChange} from useDisclosure.

- To get more idea about `useDisclosure()`, select `useDisclosure()` in your code editor & press `F12` it will show you what functions & values it returns.
- I have also `console logged isOpen` state/value, `so when you click` on card you can `see it change in console`.

***You may also read :***

- Modal Props : https://nextui.org/docs/components/modal#modal-props
- Card Props : https://nextui.org/docs/components/card#modal-props
- Server Components : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
- Client Components : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- When to use Server and Client Components : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#when-to-use-server-and-client-components

***If there's anything I left out, missed out, Please leave a comment. I will edit this answer.***